# OpenSSL の通信に ADH-AES256-SHA (TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA) を使用したい

Tags: openssl

質問です。

## 質問

OpenSSL の通信に ADH-AES256-SHA (TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA) を使用したいのですが、 ClientHello に TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA が含まれません。

SSL_set_cipher_list に ADH-AES256-SHA を指定するだけでは不足なのでしょうか？

## 背景

OpenSSL を利用したクライアントを実装しています(openssl s_client を使うわけではない)。都合により ciphers に TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA を使用したい。OpenSSL でいう ADH-AES256-SHA のことです。

[AES cipher suites from RFC3268, extending TLS v1.0](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/ciphers.html#AES-cipher-suites-from-RFC3268-extending-TLS-v1.0)

```
TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA        ADH-AES256-SHA
```

## OpenSSL のバージョン

クライアントとサーバーで通信するので、いちおうサーバー側も書きました。

サーバー側。OpenSSL のバージョンは都合により若干古いです。

```
% openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
```

クライアント側

```
% openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
```

## サーバー起動

openssl s_server を使います。証明書などを作成し openssl s_server を実行。

```
% openssl s_server -tls1 -cert server.crt -key private.key
```

## クライアントの実装

クライアントは [SSL/TLS Client - OpenSSLWiki](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL/TLS_Client) の実装を流用。

SSLv23_method() を使用しているようですが、これは TLS_method() に define されています。なので結局 TLS_method() が呼ばれます。

```c
const SSL_METHOD* method = SSLv23_method();
```

/usr/include/openssl/ssl.h

```c
#define SSLv23_method           TLS_method
```

TLS_method() は SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3 に対応しているとのことです。

[/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_CTX_new.html](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_CTX_new.html)

> TLS_method(), TLS_server_method(), TLS_client_method()
>
> These are the general-purpose version-flexible SSL/TLS methods. The
> actual protocol version used will be negotiated to the highest version
> mutually supported by the client and the server. The supported
> protocols are SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2 and TLSv1.3. Applications
> should use these methods, and avoid the version-specific methods
> described below, which are deprecated.

## ciphers に ADH-AES256-SHA が指定しても ClientHello に TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA が現れない

クライアントの SSL_set_cipher_list で ADH-AES256-SHA を指定。

```c
SSL_set_cipher_list(ssl, "ADH-AES256-SHA")
```

これをコンパイルしてクライアントを実行し、wireshark でパケットキャプチャした ClientHello は以下の通り。

TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA が含まれていることを期待したのですが、含まれていませんでした。この Cipher Suites にあるのは TLS 1.3 のものです [TLS v1.3 cipher suites](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/ciphers.html#TLS-v1.3-cipher-suites)

```
Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
    Handshake Type: Client Hello (1)
    Length: 230
    Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
    Random: b0dc55a1be1aff33062e482fb056877ff13a163ad3d57bf7…
    Session ID Length: 32
    Session ID: f7b12f84acac0e0e9a8d1e5385744637c7ec8ac0eb0c5e57…
    Cipher Suites Length: 8
    Cipher Suites (4 suites)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x1302)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (0x1303)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x1301)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV (0x00ff)
    Compression Methods Length: 1
    Compression Methods (1 method)
    Extensions Length: 149
    Extension: ec_point_formats (len=4)
    Extension: supported_groups (len=12)
    Extension: session_ticket (len=0)
    Extension: encrypt_then_mac (len=0)
    Extension: extended_master_secret (len=0)
    Extension: signature_algorithms (len=48)
    Extension: supported_versions (len=9)
    Extension: psk_key_exchange_modes (len=2)
    Extension: key_share (len=38)
```

## SSL_set_cipher_list と openssl ciphers に差異がある

いくらなんでも `"ALL:eNULL"` を指定すれば TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA が含まれているだろうと思い、`"ALL:eNULL"` を指定しましたが ClientHello に TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA は含まれませんでした。

クライアントの SSL_set_cipher_list で `"ALL:eNULL"` を指定。

```c
SSL_set_cipher_list(ssl, "ALL:eNULL")
```

wireshark でパケットキャプチャした ClientHello は以下の通り。TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA は含まれておらず。

[AES cipher suites from RFC3268, extending TLS v1.0](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/ciphers.html#AES-cipher-suites-from-RFC3268-extending-TLS-v1.0) のものが含まれていないわけではなく、たとえば TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA は含まれています。

```
Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
    Handshake Type: Client Hello (1)
    Length: 380
    Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
    Random: f849c634723342d4da78e939066a3ef04710af2c6016752b…
    Session ID Length: 32
    Session ID: 3ed8f8b1eb835effa705f7c21beddeab0c7edd362c1b01e6…
    Cipher Suites Length: 158
    Cipher Suites (79 suites)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x1302)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (0x1303)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x1301)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc02c)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc030)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x00a3)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x009f)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (0xcca9)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (0xcca8)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (0xccaa)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM_8 (0xc0af)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM (0xc0ad)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM_8 (0xc0a3)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM (0xc09f)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_ARIA_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc05d)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_ARIA_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc061)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_ARIA_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc057)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_ARIA_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc053)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02b)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x00a2)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x009e)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM_8 (0xc0ae)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM (0xc0ac)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM_8 (0xc0a2)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM (0xc09e)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_ARIA_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc05c)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_ARIA_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc060)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_ARIA_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc056)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_ARIA_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc052)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc024)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc028)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x006b)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x006a)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc073)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc077)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x00c4)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x00c3)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc023)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc027)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x0067)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x0040)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc072)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc076)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x00be)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x00bd)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc00a)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc014)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0039)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0038)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (0x0088)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (0x0087)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc009)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc013)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x0033)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x0032)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA (0x009a)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA (0x0099)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (0x0045)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (0x0044)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x009d)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM_8 (0xc0a1)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM (0xc09d)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_ARIA_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc051)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x009c)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM_8 (0xc0a0)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM (0xc09c)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_ARIA_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc050)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x003d)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x00c0)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x003c)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x00ba)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0035)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (0x0084)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x002f)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA (0x0096)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (0x0041)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_IDEA_CBC_SHA (0x0007)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV (0x00ff)
    Compression Methods Length: 1
    Compression Methods (1 method)
    Extensions Length: 149
    Extension: ec_point_formats (len=4)
    Extension: supported_groups (len=12)
    Extension: session_ticket (len=0)
    Extension: encrypt_then_mac (len=0)
    Extension: extended_master_secret (len=0)
    Extension: signature_algorithms (len=48)
    Extension: supported_versions (len=9)
    Extension: psk_key_exchange_modes (len=2)
    Extension: key_share (len=38)
```

なお `openssl ciphers -v "ALL:eNULL"` を実行すると ADH-AES256-SHA (TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA) が含まれています。

```
% openssl ciphers -v "ALL:eNULL" | sort
ADH-AES128-GCM-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=None Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ADH-AES128-SHA          SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=None Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
ADH-AES128-SHA256       TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=None Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
ADH-AES256-GCM-SHA384   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=None Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ADH-AES256-SHA          SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=None Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1      ★ ここ
ADH-AES256-SHA256       TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=None Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA256
ADH-CAMELLIA128-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=None Enc=Camellia(128) Mac=SHA1
ADH-CAMELLIA128-SHA256  TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=None Enc=Camellia(128) Mac=SHA256
ADH-CAMELLIA256-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=None Enc=Camellia(256) Mac=SHA1
ADH-CAMELLIA256-SHA256  TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=None Enc=Camellia(256) Mac=SHA256
ADH-SEED-SHA            SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=None Enc=SEED(128) Mac=SHA1
AECDH-AES128-SHA        TLSv1 Kx=ECDH     Au=None Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
AECDH-AES256-SHA        TLSv1 Kx=ECDH     Au=None Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
AECDH-NULL-SHA          TLSv1 Kx=ECDH     Au=None Enc=None      Mac=SHA1
AES128-CCM              TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AESCCM(128) Mac=AEAD
AES128-CCM8             TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AESCCM8(128) Mac=AEAD
AES128-GCM-SHA256       TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
AES128-SHA              SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
AES128-SHA256           TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
AES256-CCM              TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AESCCM(256) Mac=AEAD
AES256-CCM8             TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AESCCM8(256) Mac=AEAD
AES256-GCM-SHA384       TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
AES256-SHA              SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
AES256-SHA256           TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA256
ARIA128-GCM-SHA256      TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=ARIAGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ARIA256-GCM-SHA384      TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=ARIAGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
CAMELLIA128-SHA         SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=Camellia(128) Mac=SHA1
CAMELLIA128-SHA256      TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=Camellia(128) Mac=SHA256
CAMELLIA256-SHA         SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=Camellia(256) Mac=SHA1
CAMELLIA256-SHA256      TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=Camellia(256) Mac=SHA256
DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA256
DHE-DSS-ARIA128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=ARIAGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
DHE-DSS-ARIA256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=ARIAGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA128-SHA SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=Camellia(128) Mac=SHA1
DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=Camellia(128) Mac=SHA256
DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA256-SHA SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=Camellia(256) Mac=SHA1
DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA256-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=Camellia(256) Mac=SHA256
DHE-DSS-SEED-SHA        SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=SEED(128) Mac=SHA1
DHE-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA256 TLSv1 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
DHE-PSK-AES128-CCM      TLSv1.2 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=AESCCM(128) Mac=AEAD
DHE-PSK-AES128-CCM8     TLSv1.2 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=AESCCM8(128) Mac=AEAD
DHE-PSK-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
DHE-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA384 TLSv1 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
DHE-PSK-AES256-CCM      TLSv1.2 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=AESCCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-PSK-AES256-CCM8     TLSv1.2 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=AESCCM8(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-PSK-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-PSK-ARIA128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=ARIAGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
DHE-PSK-ARIA256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=ARIAGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-PSK-CAMELLIA128-SHA256 TLSv1 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=Camellia(128) Mac=SHA256
DHE-PSK-CAMELLIA256-SHA384 TLSv1 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=Camellia(256) Mac=SHA384
DHE-PSK-CHACHA20-POLY1305 TLSv1.2 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-PSK-NULL-SHA        SSLv3 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=None      Mac=SHA1
DHE-PSK-NULL-SHA256     TLSv1 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=None      Mac=SHA256
DHE-PSK-NULL-SHA384     TLSv1 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=None      Mac=SHA384
DHE-RSA-AES128-CCM      TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESCCM(128) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES128-CCM8     TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESCCM8(128) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
DHE-RSA-AES256-CCM      TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESCCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES256-CCM8     TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESCCM8(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA256
DHE-RSA-ARIA128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=ARIAGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-ARIA256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=ARIAGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=Camellia(128) Mac=SHA1
DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=Camellia(128) Mac=SHA256
DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=Camellia(256) Mac=SHA1
DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=Camellia(256) Mac=SHA256
DHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-SEED-SHA        SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=SEED(128) Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-ARIA128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=ARIAGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ARIA256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=ARIAGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-CCM  TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESCCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-CCM8 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESCCM8(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA  TLSv1 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-CCM  TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESCCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-CCM8 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESCCM8(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA  TLSv1 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
ECDHE-ECDSA-ARIA128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=ARIAGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-ARIA256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=ARIAGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=Camellia(128) Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-ECDSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=Camellia(256) Mac=SHA384
ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-NULL-SHA    TLSv1 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=None      Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA TLSv1 Kx=ECDHEPSK Au=PSK  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA256 TLSv1 Kx=ECDHEPSK Au=PSK  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA TLSv1 Kx=ECDHEPSK Au=PSK  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA384 TLSv1 Kx=ECDHEPSK Au=PSK  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
ECDHE-PSK-CAMELLIA128-SHA256 TLSv1 Kx=ECDHEPSK Au=PSK  Enc=Camellia(128) Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-PSK-CAMELLIA256-SHA384 TLSv1 Kx=ECDHEPSK Au=PSK  Enc=Camellia(256) Mac=SHA384
ECDHE-PSK-CHACHA20-POLY1305 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDHEPSK Au=PSK  Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-PSK-NULL-SHA      TLSv1 Kx=ECDHEPSK Au=PSK  Enc=None      Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-PSK-NULL-SHA256   TLSv1 Kx=ECDHEPSK Au=PSK  Enc=None      Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-PSK-NULL-SHA384   TLSv1 Kx=ECDHEPSK Au=PSK  Enc=None      Mac=SHA384
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA    TLSv1 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA    TLSv1 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
ECDHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=Camellia(128) Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=Camellia(256) Mac=SHA384
ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-RSA-NULL-SHA      TLSv1 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=None      Mac=SHA1
IDEA-CBC-SHA            SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=IDEA(128) Mac=SHA1
NULL-MD5                SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=None      Mac=MD5 
NULL-SHA                SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=None      Mac=SHA1
NULL-SHA256             TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=None      Mac=SHA256
PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA256   TLSv1 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
PSK-AES128-CCM          TLSv1.2 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AESCCM(128) Mac=AEAD
PSK-AES128-CCM8         TLSv1.2 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AESCCM8(128) Mac=AEAD
PSK-AES128-GCM-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA384   TLSv1 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
PSK-AES256-CCM          TLSv1.2 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AESCCM(256) Mac=AEAD
PSK-AES256-CCM8         TLSv1.2 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AESCCM8(256) Mac=AEAD
PSK-AES256-GCM-SHA384   TLSv1.2 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
PSK-ARIA128-GCM-SHA256  TLSv1.2 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=ARIAGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
PSK-ARIA256-GCM-SHA384  TLSv1.2 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=ARIAGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
PSK-CAMELLIA128-SHA256  TLSv1 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=Camellia(128) Mac=SHA256
PSK-CAMELLIA256-SHA384  TLSv1 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=Camellia(256) Mac=SHA384
PSK-CHACHA20-POLY1305   TLSv1.2 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD
PSK-NULL-SHA            SSLv3 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=None      Mac=SHA1
PSK-NULL-SHA256         TLSv1 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=None      Mac=SHA256
PSK-NULL-SHA384         TLSv1 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=None      Mac=SHA384
RSA-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
RSA-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA256 TLSv1 Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
RSA-PSK-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
RSA-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
RSA-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA384 TLSv1 Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
RSA-PSK-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
RSA-PSK-ARIA128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA  Enc=ARIAGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
RSA-PSK-ARIA256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA  Enc=ARIAGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
RSA-PSK-CAMELLIA128-SHA256 TLSv1 Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA  Enc=Camellia(128) Mac=SHA256
RSA-PSK-CAMELLIA256-SHA384 TLSv1 Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA  Enc=Camellia(256) Mac=SHA384
RSA-PSK-CHACHA20-POLY1305 TLSv1.2 Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA  Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD
RSA-PSK-NULL-SHA        SSLv3 Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA  Enc=None      Mac=SHA1
RSA-PSK-NULL-SHA256     TLSv1 Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA  Enc=None      Mac=SHA256
RSA-PSK-NULL-SHA384     TLSv1 Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA  Enc=None      Mac=SHA384
SEED-SHA                SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=SEED(128) Mac=SHA1
SRP-AES-128-CBC-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=SRP      Au=SRP  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
SRP-AES-256-CBC-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=SRP      Au=SRP  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
SRP-DSS-AES-128-CBC-SHA SSLv3 Kx=SRP      Au=DSS  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
SRP-DSS-AES-256-CBC-SHA SSLv3 Kx=SRP      Au=DSS  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
SRP-RSA-AES-128-CBC-SHA SSLv3 Kx=SRP      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
SRP-RSA-AES-256-CBC-SHA SSLv3 Kx=SRP      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256  TLSv1.3 Kx=any      Au=any  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384  TLSv1.3 Kx=any      Au=any  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 TLSv1.3 Kx=any      Au=any  Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

自己レスです。

本家の issue に同じものがありました。

[using ADH on new openssl · Issue #8408 · openssl/openssl](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/8408)

> `openssl s_client -cipher 'ADH:@SECLEVEL=0' -tls1 -connect 10.xxx.xxx.xxx:8729`
>
> OpenSSL 1.1.0 implements "security levels". The default security level
> is 1. ADH ciphersuites are in security level 0 and so are blocked by
> default.

ということで、クライアントは API 呼び出しに `@SECLEVEL=0` を追加して

```c
SSL_set_cipher_list(ssl, "ADH-AES256-SHA:@SECLEVEL=0");
```

サーバーにも `@SECLEVEL=0` を追加。これでハンドシェイクはできました。

```
% openssl s_server -cipher 'ALL:@SECLEVEL=0' -nocert
```